# Neomutt run command to attach file on macro key press

Tags: zsh, mutt, ranger

I'm trying to use ranger to attach files to a mail in NeoMutt. What I have so far is

1. Run ranger to select the file to attach and save its name to `/tmp/muttattach` with

> ```
> ranger --choosefile=/tmp/muttattach
> ```

2. Define a macro to read `muttattach`

> ```
> macro compose V "<attach-file>`cat /tmp/muttattach`<enter>"
> ```

The problem is, the macro is only run at startup. When I press <kbd>V</kbd> in the compose screen it does not update the filename.

I have also tried to run ranger directly from mutt with `<pipe-message>` as they do [here](https://gist.github.com/manolomartinez/7082024) to download attachments but haven't managed to get it working on zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a config file e.g. **~/.neomutt/attach.macro** contain just the macro definition:

```
macro compose W \
"<attach-file>`cat /tmp/muttattach`<enter>" \
"attach file"
```

Define another macro which does following:

1. source the config file above **~/.neomutt/attach.macro**
2. execute command **push W** (bound to a newly defined macro)

```
macro compose V \
"<enter-command>source ~/.neomutt/attach.macro<enter>\
<enter-command>push W<enter>" \
"redefine macro and attach"
```

So pressing `V` will source again the config file, which redefines the macro with fresh content of /tmp/muttattach. And executes it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jakub's answer I managed to do what I wanted and run ranger from within mutt to select the file. Here's the macro:

```
macro compose V \ 
"<shell-escape> ranger --choosefile=/tmp/muttattach<enter>\  
<enter-command>source ~/.config/neomutt/attach.macro<enter>\   
<enter-command>push W<enter>"\   
"open ranger, redefine macro and attach"
```

And the content of `~/.config/neomutt/attach.macro`

```
macro compose W \
"<attach-file>`cat /tmp/muttattach`<enter>"\
"attach file"
```

Comment: You might be also interested in https://github.com/anufrievroman/Neomutt-File-Picker mentioned in similar neomutt issue/feature request: https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/2738#issuecomment-738712090

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works almost perfectly. The only issue I get is, that after attaching  a file I'm prompted to enter a keyID for the mail recipient...Any idea what I'm doing wrong?