# mutt: determine local path of current mail

Tags: linux, email, mutt, maildir

**CHALLENGE**

I want to determine the local path of the currently viewed mail within mutt and transfer it to a bash script, before or after saving the mail to a local project folder.

**CONCEPT**

I am using `mutt` together with `offlineimap` and `msmtp` in order to decouple my mail infrastructure from the necessity of a permanent internet connection. In doing so, I find my mails within the mailfile structure where each `<PROJECT>` and `<ACCOUNT>` may live in its own local folder structure:

```
Mail/
|-- <PROJECT>/
|   |-- cur/
|   |   |-- 1584016380.RPi-18:2,
|   |   |-- 1595241604.RPi-18:2,
|   |   |-- 1603636018.RPi-18:2,
|   |   `-- 1612159655.RPi-18:2,
|   |-- new/
|   `-- tmp/
|-- <ACCOUNT>/
|   |-- DRAFTS/
|   |   |-- cur/
|   |   |-- new/
|   |   `-- tmp/
|   |-- INBOX/
...
```

When I browse my mail (using the index or pager view in mutt), I can select, tag, delete, ... open the respective mail element which is read by mutt from the sketched folder structure.

Now, I want to save the current message using mutt's `save-message` function. But beforehand (or after the save), I want to automatically extract the message's attachment and possibly do some other stuff using the mail contents.

I already wrote a bash script which reads in the path of a mail file, e.g. `~/Mail/<PROJECT>/cur/1584016380.RPi-18:2` as its argument, and then stores the mail's attachments in a predefined location using the `mu` command.

**PROBLEM**

I have looked within the available mutt variables (`folder`, `spoolfile`, `from`, ...) in order to find anything that would tell me where my currently viewed mail file is actually located. But I could not find anything. So, I don't know which path to pass to my bash script for it to find the mail locally.

**Is there anything usable, here?**

Comment: What about piping the message to the script? Would it solve the issue for you? You can write a macro doing the pipe-message and save/copy.

Comment: Good idea. I hadn't thought about piping, yet. Will try to modify my code to accept piped content directly.

Comment: There seems to be a problem, though. When using `pipe-message`, my target script does not know WHERE the piped messasge is to be saved. a target folder is determined while using mutt's `save` command. not before that. I see two options:

(1) is there a way to set a target folder for a message (which is originally done when using the `save` command) and transfer it to the script? and afterwards use it in the `save` command?

(2) alternatively, the `save` command could be executed first, then pipe the message to the script. would there be a way to determine the target folder used by `save`?

Comment: by the way, I'm assuming, that the function `pipe-message` accepts an **executable script** as a target. not only a file. otherwise the function might better be called `redirect-message`, eh? would this be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to compose an answer, because this is becomming quite large to be resolved in discussion in comments under the question.

I understand the *project* differes for different senders, subjects or body content.

You'll need two macros like here [Neomutt run command to attach file on macro key press](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612154/85046)

The first macro does the job and needs to be in a separate file - because the shell part is expanded on macros definition. That's why You need to redefine it by the second macro that defines the first one and executes it.

*~/.mutt/dynamic_macro*

```
"<pipe-message>/path/to/your/script<enter>\
<save-message>`cat /tmp/mutt_project`<enter>" \
"pipe message to extract attachments and save message"
```

*~/.mutt/muttrc*

```
macro index ,S \
"<enter-command>source ~/.mutt/dynamic_macro<enter>\
<enter-command>push ,s<enter>" \
"redefine macro and run it"
```

Now here is nonworking an example of `/path/to/your/script` in pseudo code (bash like). The script reads the message from stdin, parses headers or body to determine the *project* name (mailbox name) and iterates over parts to save the attachments - probably to some directory and subdirectories by projects?

```
detect_project(){
  # parse $content to detect project from body/headers
  # save the project name to /tmp/mutt_project for the 1st macro
  # and output on stdout for save_attachemnts()
  echo $result > /tmp/mutt_project
  echo $result
}

save_attachments(){
  # parse $content, iterate over parts of message from $content,
  # extract attachments, decode, save to:
  #/root_directory_with_attachments/$project/$your_filename
}

main(){
  content=$(cat) # read the stdin and save it into variable
  project=$(detect_project)
  save_attachments
}

main
```

Suggestions:

1. use language that has library for working with emails that can access the parts, decoded them etc.
2. I'm convinced that the example above won't work with tag-prefix if you'll tag multiple messages from a different projects. The reason is that macro is executed once and all messages would be piped into /path/to/your/script at once, but the argument of `<save-message>` will contain project detected from the last message

---

Different solution: move from mutt to neomut and mu to notmuch. Neomutt has a good built-in support for notmuch. Everything here could be done by notmuch post-new hook.
It's perfect for your usecase, running on background without any need of neomutt macros and removes the limitation of tag-prefix of original solution. Nomtuch post-new hook runs everytime after You sync Your messages.

- it can tag messages based on from/to/cc/subject headers body content or other tags,
- saving an attachment is also possible by post-new hook.

If You're interested in this, leave here a comment here and I'll expand the answer.